# TensorFlow object detection error when training

Tags: object, tensorflow, detection

Hej Guys !

I am trying to run locally the cat example and I got stuck on the trainning step. I get this very long error. Could someone help me out to understand what is wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

The command:
bertalan@mbqs:~/tensorflow/models$ python object_detection/train.py --logtostderr --pipeline_config_path=/home/bertalan/tensorflow/models/object_detection/samples/configs/Myfaster_rcnn_resnet101_pets.config --train_dir=TrainCat

Here the output with error:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
    INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
    INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
    INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
    INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
    INFO:tensorflow:Summary name Learning Rate is illegal; using Learning_Rate instead.
    INFO:tensorflow:Summary name /clone_loss is illegal; using clone_loss instead.
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py:93: UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. This may consume a large amount of memory.
      "Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor of unknown shape. "
    2017-07-26 11:27:18.416172: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
    2017-07-26 11:27:18.416220: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
    2017-07-26 11:27:18.416248: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
    2017-07-26 11:27:20.437921: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:669] Ignoring device specification /device:GPU:0 for node 'prefetch_queue_Dequeue' because the input edge from 'prefetch_queue' is a reference connection and already has a device field set to /device:CPU:0
    INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /home/bertalan/tensorflow/models/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco_11_06_2017/model.ckpt
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.179612: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/beta not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.179639: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv2/weights not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.179673: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/moving_mean not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.179612: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/gamma not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.185127: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/moving_variance not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.187191: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv3/weights not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.187614: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/shortcut/BatchNorm/gamma not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.188036: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/shortcut/BatchNorm/beta not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.188324: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv2/BatchNorm/moving_variance not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.189131: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/shortcut/weights not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.190319: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/shortcut/BatchNorm/moving_variance not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.190613: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/shortcut/BatchNorm/moving_mean not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.190923: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv2/BatchNorm/moving_mean not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.191949: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_2/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/moving_mean not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.192728: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_2/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/gamma not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.193354: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_2/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/moving_variance not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.194102: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key 

    ...

    2017-07-26 11:27:25.204869: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_3/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/gamma not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.205198: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_3/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/moving_mean not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.205799: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/moving_mean not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.205853: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_3/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/moving_variance not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.209234: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_3/bottleneck_v1/conv2/BatchNorm/beta not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.210446: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_3/bottleneck_v1/conv1/weights not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.210829: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/gamma not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.212274: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_3/bottleneck_v1/conv2/BatchNorm/gamma not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.212305: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_3/bottleneck_v1/conv2/BatchNorm/moving_mean not found in checkpoint Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_20/bottleneck_v1/conv2/BatchNorm/moving_variance not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.613441: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_20/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/beta not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.613721: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_20/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/gamma not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.615790: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_20/bottleneck_v1/conv3/weights not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.615937: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_20/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/moving_mean not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.616601: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_20/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/moving_variance not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.616872: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_21/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/beta not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.617185: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_22/bottleneck_v1/conv2/BatchNorm/moving_variance not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.617505: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_21/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/gamma not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.618701: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_21/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/moving_mean not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.618781: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_22/bottleneck_v1/conv2/BatchNorm/moving_mean not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.620022: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_21/bottleneck_v1/conv1/weights not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.621149: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_21/bottleneck_v1/conv2/BatchNorm/beta not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.621225: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_22/bottleneck_v1/conv2/BatchNorm/gamma not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.621225: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_21/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/moving_variance not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.623092: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_21/bottleneck_v1/conv2/BatchNorm/gamma not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.624135: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_21/bottleneck_v1/conv2/BatchNorm/moving_variance not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.627327: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_21/bottleneck_v1/conv2/BatchNorm/moving_mean not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.627572: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_21/bottleneck_v1/conv2/weights not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.628414: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_21/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/gamma not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.628844: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_21/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/moving_mean not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.629118: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_22/bottleneck_v1/conv2/BatchNorm/beta not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.629480: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_21/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/beta not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.629624: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_21/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/moving_variance not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.630848: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_22/bottleneck_v1/conv1/weights not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.631122: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_22/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/beta not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.631167: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_21/bottleneck_v1/conv3/weights not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.632471: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_22/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/gamma not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.633056: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_22/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/moving_variance not found in checkpoint
    2017-07-26 11:27:25.633295: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1152] Not found: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_22/bottleneck_v1/conv1/BatchNorm/moving_mean not found in checkpoint
    INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError'>, Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/beta not found in checkpoint
         [[Node: save/RestoreV2_475 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2_475/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_475/shape_and_slices)]]

    Caused by op u'save/RestoreV2_475', defined at:
      File "object_detection/train.py", line 198, in <module>
        tf.app.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
        _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
      File "object_detection/train.py", line 194, in main
        worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir)
      File "/home/bertalan/tensorflow/models/object_detection/trainer.py", line 216, in train
        from_detection_checkpoint=train_config.from_detection_checkpoint)
      File "/home/bertalan/tensorflow/models/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py", line 1447, in restore_fn
        saver = tf.train.Saver(first_stage_variables)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1056, in __init__
        self.build()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1086, in build
        restore_sequentially=self._restore_sequentially)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 691, in build
        restore_sequentially, reshape)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 407, in _AddRestoreOps
        tensors = self.restore_op(filename_tensor, saveable, preferred_shard)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 247, in restore_op
        [spec.tensor.dtype])[0])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 669, in restore_v2
        dtypes=dtypes, name=name)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
        op_def=op_def)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
        original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
        self._traceback = _extract_stack()

    NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/beta not found in checkpoint
         [[Node: save/RestoreV2_475 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2_475/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_475/shape_and_slices)]]

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "object_detection/train.py", line 198, in <module>
        tf.app.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
        _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
      File "object_detection/train.py", line 194, in main
        worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir)
      File "/home/bertalan/tensorflow/models/object_detection/trainer.py", line 290, in train
        saver=saver)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py", line 725, in train
        master, start_standard_services=False, config=session_config) as sess:
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
        return self.gen.next()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 960, in managed_session
        self.stop(close_summary_writer=close_summary_writer)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 788, in stop
        stop_grace_period_secs=self._stop_grace_secs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 389, in join
        six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 949, in managed_session
        start_standard_services=start_standard_services)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 706, in prepare_or_wait_for_session
        init_feed_dict=self._init_feed_dict, init_fn=self._init_fn)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py", line 264, in prepare_session
        init_fn(sess)
      File "/home/bertalan/tensorflow/models/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py", line 1450, in restore
        saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_path)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1457, in restore
        {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 778, in run
        run_metadata_ptr)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 982, in _run
        feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1032, in _do_run
        target_list, options, run_metadata)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1052, in _do_call
        raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
    tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/beta not found in checkpoint
         [[Node: save/RestoreV2_475 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2_475/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_475/shape_and_slices)]]

    Caused by op u'save/RestoreV2_475', defined at:
      File "object_detection/train.py", line 198, in <module>
        tf.app.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
        _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
      File "object_detection/train.py", line 194, in main
        worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir)
      File "/home/bertalan/tensorflow/models/object_detection/trainer.py", line 216, in train
        from_detection_checkpoint=train_config.from_detection_checkpoint)
      File "/home/bertalan/tensorflow/models/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py", line 1447, in restore_fn
        saver = tf.train.Saver(first_stage_variables)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1056, in __init__
        self.build()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1086, in build
        restore_sequentially=self._restore_sequentially)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 691, in build
        restore_sequentially, reshape)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 407, in _AddRestoreOps
        tensors = self.restore_op(filename_tensor, saveable, preferred_shard)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 247, in restore_op
        [spec.tensor.dtype])[0])
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 669, in restore_v2
        dtypes=dtypes, name=name)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
        op_def=op_def)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
        original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
        self._traceback = _extract_stack()

    NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block4/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/conv3/BatchNorm/beta not found in checkpoint
         [[Node: save/RestoreV2_475 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2_475/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2_475/shape_and_slices)]]
```

By the way, here is my config file:

```
# Faster R-CNN with Resnet-101 (v1) configured for the Oxford-IIIT Pet Dataset.
# Users should configure the fine_tune_checkpoint field in the train config as
# well as the label_map_path and input_path fields in the train_input_reader and
# eval_input_reader. Search for "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED" to find the fields that
# should be configured.

model {
  faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 37
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 600
        max_dimension: 1024
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'faster_rcnn_resnet101'
      first_stage_features_stride: 16
    }
    first_stage_anchor_generator {
      grid_anchor_generator {
        scales: [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        aspect_ratios: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        height_stride: 16
        width_stride: 16
      }
    }
    first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
      op: CONV
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 0.0
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          stddev: 0.01
        }
      }
    }
    first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
    first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.7
    first_stage_max_proposals: 300
    first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
    initial_crop_size: 14
    maxpool_kernel_size: 2
    maxpool_stride: 2
    second_stage_box_predictor {
      mask_rcnn_box_predictor {
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 1.0
        fc_hyperparams {
          op: FC
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            variance_scaling_initializer {
              factor: 1.0
              uniform: true
              mode: FAN_AVG
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.0
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 300
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        manual_step_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0003
          schedule {
            step: 0
            learning_rate: .0003
          }
          schedule {
            step: 900000
            learning_rate: .00003
          }
          schedule {
            step: 1200000
            learning_rate: .000003
          }
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  gradient_clipping_by_norm: 10.0
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/home/bertalan/tensorflow/models/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco_11_06_2017/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "python /home/bertalan/tensorflow/models/pet_train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "/home/bertalan/tensorflow/models/object_detection/data/pet_label_map.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 2000
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/home/bertalan/tensorflow/models/pet_val.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "/home/bertalan/tensorflow/models/object_detection/data/pet_label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your checkpoint model and feature extracting model is different.

Comment: Thanks ! After all the work is always a distraction that kill us  It works now. But it is using all my cpus and memory until it gets killed. Anyway to manage that in configure file ?

Comment: you can try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38187808/how-can-i-run-tensorflow-on-one-single-core if you are training on cpu.