# Tensorflow error: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dct_method'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, object-detection

When running the [Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) with the current release of Tensorflow-Gpu (1.5), the following error gets thrown, when trying to train on a custom set of images.

```
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
INFO:tensorflow:Scale of 0 disables regularizer.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\trainer.py:228: create_global_step (from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.create_global_step
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 167, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\Vic-10-3\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 124, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "train.py", line 163, in main
    worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir)
  File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\trainer.py", line 235, in train
    train_config.prefetch_queue_capacity, data_augmentation_options)
  File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\trainer.py", line 59, in create_input_queue
    tensor_dict = create_tensor_dict_fn()
  File "train.py", line 120, in get_next
    dataset_builder.build(config)).get_next()
  File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py", line 138, in build
    label_map_proto_file=label_map_proto_file)
  File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\data_decoders\tf_example_decoder.py", line 110, in __init__
    dct_method=dct_method),
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dct_method'
```

The expected behavior would be to run the actual training, but apparently something became incompatible with the latest release.

Instruction for reproducing the error: [Follow the tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md) and train on a custom dataset.

Comment: Only the error message is not enough to help you out. First google search returned this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323136/tensorflow-object-detection-error-when-training Maybe it will help? Add some code, and data that we could look at to help you.

Comment: I have just got this error too when I upgrade to TensorFlow 1.5. And going to ask this question on the stack overflow, but I saw this post and directly upvoted.

Comment: @Umberto there is no need to show code, I also have the same problem, I happen when trying to train own dataset using one of the pre-trained modules from object detection API. So I did not write even one line of code, just preparing the data, and then convert it to TF record and then start training, it was working well with 1.4 but failed with 1.5. It is what that I have asked the same question on Github https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3421

Comment: I've got a feeling that this might be because of the image names.....keep me posted of you figure it out.

Comment: @Traviccc No. it is not because of image names, it is just a bug.

Answer (score 6):

This error is due to the incompatibility of file tf_example_decoder.py with the Tensorflow installed.

In file models/research/object_detection/data_decoders/tf_example_decoder.py:

line 28:

`slim_example_decoder = tf.contrib.slim.tfexample_decoder`

line 104:

```
self.items_to_handlers = {
    fields.InputDataFields.image:
        slim_example_decoder.Image(
            image_key='image/encoded',
            format_key='image/format',
            channels=3,
            dct_method=dct_method),....
            .....
            ....
            ..
            .
            }
```

slim_example_decoder.Image  is tf.contrib.slim.tfexample_decoder.Image

In Tensorflow 1.5 source code `tf.contrib.slim.tfexample_decoder.Image` doesn't have `dct_method` argument. Therefore when `dct_method` argument is passed it throws an error.

A simple hack would be to not pass this argument. So edit tf_example_decoder.py line 110 to remove `dct_method=dct_method`. I tried this and it worked and didn't had any effect on training.

Comment: I did that. And now I got another similar error reading this:
AttributeError: 'InputReader' object has no attribute 'num_parallel_map_calls', then I removed that as well, and yet another similar error.

Comment: Yes, it was working for me. Thanks!! @Traviccc you can try to completely reinstall TensorFlow and Models, maybe it will work.