# Specifying CPUs for use in Keras Tensorflow Model Inference

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Alright. I know that we can limit the number of cores used by a Keras (TF backend) model by using the following method:

```
 K.set_session(K.tf.Session(config=K.tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=2, inter_op_parallelism_threads=2,  device_count = {'CPU': 2})))
```

And we can specify individual tensor operations like this:

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
```

But what if we want to specify a list of individual CPUs to be used by the Keras model?

Comment: Maybe this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38187808/how-can-i-run-tensorflow-on-one-single-core

Comment: Hi @AbhishekSingh. No, unfortunately this thread is about liming the number of cores, not specifying which cores you want the processes to run on.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can change processor affinity in Tensorflow, that's the level of operating system.

However, Linux has an useful tool `taskset` to help you.

For example,

`taskset --cpu-list 0,1 python3 main.py`

will assign core 0 and core 1 to the process that runs `python3 main.py`.

You can verify that with `htop`.

Comment: Wow just when it took me hours to come up with this solution and finally did it, I read your answer... -.- Hopefully others will read it before they search, because this solution works wonderfully (+1!)