# How can I run Tensorflow on one single core, single thread CPP?

Tags: c++, multithreading, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-c++

I am trying to restrict the number of threads that TensorFlow spawns. In python, I understand we need to use the following steps as pointed out [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38187808/how-can-i-run-tensorflow-on-one-single-core). I was trying to do the same in CPP, but it doesn't seem that straight forward.
Questions:

1. How to modify intra_op_parallelism_threads and inter_op_parallelism_threads correctly?
2. How to modify the device_count to control the core as well?

```
SessionOptions options;
ConfigProto* config = &options.config;
string key = "CPU";
//not sure if this is the correct way to do it.
(*config->mutable_device_count())[key] = 1; 
config->set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(1);
config->set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(1);
```

Comment: If you know, can you please share the solution for how to run TensorFlow on single core, single thread?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question 1:

```
tensorflow::SessionOptions options;
tensorflow::ConfigProto & config = options.config;
config.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(1);
config.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(1);
session->reset(tensorflow::NewSession(options));
```

This will reduce the **total number** of threads (**but not to 1**) generated by TensorFlow. The **total number** of threads generated by TensorFlow will still be multiple, depending on the number of cores in the CPU. In most of the cases, only one thread will be active while others will be in sleeping mode. I don't think it is possible to have a **single-threaded** TensorFlow.

The following github issues support my point of view.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33627
https://github.com/usnistgov/frvt/issues/30

Comment: You are absolutely right @fisa. What worked for me was the following:  SessionOptions options;
    ConfigProto* config = &options.config;
 //single thread control//
 config->set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(1);
 config->set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(1);
    
    fSession.reset(NewSession(options));

Comment: What is the answer to Question 2?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to 1 as Fisa pointed out is correct. With just minor adjustment as config is a pointer.

```
 SessionOptions options;
ConfigProto* config = &options.config;
//single thread control//
config->set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(1);
config->set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(1);    
fSession.reset(NewSession(options));
```